# Why does one code work but not the other?

Tags: java

I'm attempting the [makeBricks problem on codingbat.com](http://codingbat.com/prob/p183562) as follows:

> We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long.  We have a
>   number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). 
>   Return true if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the
>   given bricks.

If I simply run a test for which scenarios will NOT work (Code A), the code passes all codingbat's run tests.

**Code A**

```
return(!( goal > (small+(big*5))  ||  (goal % 5 > small) ));
```

If on the other hand I want to drag it out and test it for all possible scenarios where the brick combinations WILL work (Code B), the code passes all tests on codingbat except for the very last one which only says "other tests."  Since I don't know what these other tests are, I'm stumped as to why Code B will not work.  Any thoughts?

**Code B**

```
int allBigSize = big*5;

if(goal > (small+(big*5))  ) return false; //tests all small and big

if(small >= goal) return true; //tests only small

if((big*5) >= goal && goal%5 == 0) return true; //tests only big

if((big*5) % (goal-small) == 0) return true; //tests combo of big and small

else {
    return(small >= Math.abs((goal-(big*5))-small));
}
```

Comment: Why does one code what?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What are your expected results and what those outputted?

Comment: @nhgrif: "Do, or it do not. There is no "why"."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t get your motivation for writing the second version; it does not handle more cases, it just adds redundancy (and errors).

When converting your first version to a more readable form (Eclipse can do this automatically, just press `Ctrl`+`1` and choose “Push negation down” and “Remove extra parentheses”) we got:

```
    return goal<=small+big*5 && small >= goal%5;
```

---

Now compare it with you second form:

```
if(goal > (small+(big*5))  ) return false; //tests all small and big
```

This is the same as the first term of your first form: `goal<=small+big*5` is required.

```
if(small >= goal) return true; //tests only small
```

This is handled by your first variant: just check what happens if `big` is zero, and it will remain `true` when `big` is bigger than zero

```
if((big*5) >= goal && goal%5 == 0) return true; //tests only big
```

Now check what happens when `small` is zero and then if it is bigger than zero: your first variant already covers this too.

```
if((big*5) % (goal-small) == 0) return true; //tests combo of big and small
```

Now the errors come in: what shall this mean? Well, most probably you wanted to express the same thing than your first variant does, but you failed this time.

```
else {
    return(small >= Math.abs((goal-(big*5))-small));
}
```

And here, I’m lost. I have no clue what you even *wanted* to express…